# Angular factory and controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am trying to learn about using factory with controller. I have seen one example with:

```
angular.module('flapperNews')
  .factory('posts', ['$http', function($http) {
    var o = {
      posts: []
    }
    o.getPosts = function() {
      return $http.get('api/posts').success(function(data) {
        return data
      })
    };
    o.create = function(post) {
      return $http.post('api/posts', post).success(function(data) {
        o.posts.push(data);
      })
    };
    return o
  }])
```

When I console.log(o.getPosts()), it returned the following:

```
Promise {$$state: Object}
$$state
:
Object
pending
:
undefined
processScheduled
:
false
status
:
1
value
:
Object
config
:
Object
data
:
Array[6]
0
:
Object
_id
:
"576d4904f2aa867dadb7b286"
link
:
"aaa"
title
:
"nice weather in Australia"
upvotes
:
0
__proto__
:
Object
__defineGetter__
:
__defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__
:
__defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__
:
__lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__
:
__lookupSetter__()
constructor
:
Object()
hasOwnProperty
:
hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf
:
```

The data I wanted is under Array[6] which is under $$state, does anyone have any idea what this is and how does one normally extract that data?
The data is supposed to be passed to my controller like so:

```
 $stateProvider
   .state('home', {
       url: '/home',
       templateUrl: 'views/posts.html',
       controller: 'PostCtrl',
       controllerAs: 'posts',
       resolve: {
         postPromise: ['posts', function(posts) {
           console.log(posts.getPosts())
           return posts.getPosts();
         }]
       }
   });
```

Note:This is taken from an online tutorial. Would really appreciate it if someone can shed some light on this as I am new to factory etc. The current code doesn't return anything to my view, can you tell me where I have gone wrong?

Edited/Added: This is the implementation of controller. When I console.log(posts.posts) it returns an empty array []. Any ideas?

```
 angular.module('flapperNews')



     .controller('PostCtrl', [
      '$scope','posts',
        function($scope,posts){

          $scope.posts=posts.posts;

      $scope.incrementUpvotes=function(post){
              post.upvotes+=1
            }

             $scope.addPost = function(){
              if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
              posts.create({
                title: $scope.title,
                link: $scope.link,
              });
              $scope.title = '';
              $scope.link = '';
            };


    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you calling the factory's method in your controller? You are making an $http request which returns a promise.

You can learn about promises here:http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html.

In short you can see promises as functions that execute right away but return data in the future (not right away).  You will have to wait until the promise "resolves" to get the data.  That is why is good to wrap any code that needs data from a promise, within the promise function itself.

In your **controller** you should call the **factory method(getPosts())** like this:

```
posts.getPosts().then(function(response){

    $scope.news = response.data;  <---here is where you get your data for your news.  You cant not declare **$scope.data** outside this promise function because you will miss the data.   

});
```

Don't forget to **inject** your **posts** service/factory in your **controller** like this:

```
controller(['posts',function(posts){ ... });
```

You can also get the data in your **route** like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home',{
        url:'/home',
        templateUrl:'views/posts.html',
        controller:'PostCtrl',
        controllerAs:'posts',
        resolve:{
            postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){

                return posts.getPosts().then(function(response){

                     return response.data

                });

            }]
       }
    })
```

Then in your **controller** you can **inject** the **postPromise** like this:

```
controller(['postPromise',function(postPromise){ ... });
```

Now you can **assign** the data to a variable in your **controller** like this:

```
$scope.news = postPromise;
```

Hope I answered your question.  If I misunderstood please give more details or provide a codepen.

Comment: I am following the tute here:https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#wiring-everything-up but postPromise wasnt' injected into any controller. I am thus guessing the tutorial is not complete. Sorry I explained wrongly, posts.getPosts() wasn't implemented in any controller, it only exist under resolve under the stateprovider route, so that the posts appear automatically when the page loads. I will try out all your suggestions and see how it goes. Thanks heaps!!

Comment: You have to inject the postPromise to your controller... it has the data returned back from your post service.  Look at the **Finishing Off Comments** section of your tutorial then look at the 3rd and 4th purple boxes and you will see he is injecting **post** in the controller.  **post** is not the service but the object that contains the data loaded in the route resolve. :)

Comment: I have added controller code above - only the service 'posts' has been injected as per the tutorial but not "postPromise'. This is apparently so that the posts data will not go out of scope and other controllers can use the data by injecting the service 'posts'. In the code  resolve:{
            postPromise: ['posts', function(posts), what is the first argument 'posts'? I have read other articles but that argument is always left out. Anyway, I don't think I am meant to inject both 'posts' service and postPromise into the controller.

Comment: Hey i notice ur service posts is making some api calls. Do you have the url for the service?   You can't store data to $http.post('api/post') or get data from $http.get('api/post) with no url. Maybe u don't want to share the url but i just want to make sure u have one. I also show you how to use the service in a controller and also in a route.  Please create a codepen.io pen and show the code. Its difficult to answer the question when the  you ask to check the tutorial and the tutorial switches from postsPromise to post midway. 

Comment: No, there's no url or rather the full url is not necessary as all my apps work just like this. Also I am happy to close this issue as I managed to get it to work by just injecting the resolve function ie postPromise into my controller but there are cases where it may be better to activate the GET in the controller rather than using resolve, still learning... Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify, it was an api call to localhost not external service.

Comment: Got it thats is what i figured. Awesome that u have it working.  And yes sometimes u need to load data before the controller gets loaded. Using the resolve in the route is the best option for the use case. Otherwise u can just call the service in the controller to load the data as u needed.  Remember u want to have ur controllers "thin" (most logic in the controllers will be ui related like button clicks , setting options, etc) so ur business logic will be place in ur services/factories.  Also services/factories are use to communicate between controllers, directives and other services. 